# Itemized deduction when not on lease, utility contracts, etc

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am a single individual in the United States on a work visa. My job makes me move around the country, often at short notice. I therefore try to find living arrangements where I don't have to be a lessee/co-lessee, i.e., I pay my room-mate (the actual lessee) directly. For 2012, I was in OH for 2 months in a hotel and then in NJ for the remaining 10 in an apartment.

If I want to itemize my deductions, am I SOL because I cannot produce any bills/invoices with my name on them? I have paid rent a couple of times (not just my portion but the entire monthly rent for the apartment) directly and can produce credit card bills for proof. Are they enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renting an apartment, condo or house doesn't qualify you for deductions related to interest and property tax. It doesn't matter if you are on the lease or not.

Other deductions such as those related to state income tax, donations to charity and major medical expenses are available to everybody regardless of their housing situation.